# MySQL; Make a single row if multiple rows have the same id

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I've the following table called `test`:
[image: table]

As you can see, some rows have the same id.

I want to merge the duplicate rows into one and create a new column for the additional value(s).

The resulting table may be a temporally table.

This is what I need as result:
[image: result]

Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT will do something similar, but it will give the values in one field (something like 1,'Peter,George')

Comment: @NigelRen Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple GROUP_CONCAT example

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR ';') FROM test GROUP BY id;
```

Group by will bring all of the records with the same ID together, the group_concat will add all of the values for the same grouping together.

Comment: @David Use group_concat(value separator ';')